# Fazer um algoritmo para calcular o número de dias decorridos entre duas datas em c++

Tags: c++, algoritmo

Galera tenho esse algoritimo:

> Fazer um algoritmo para calcular o número de dias decorridos entre
>   duas datas (considerar também a ocorrência de anos bissextos),
>   sabendo-se que: a) cada par de datas é lido numa linha, a última linha
>   contém o número do dia negativo b) a primeira data na linha é sempre a
>   mais antiga. O ano está digitado com quatro dígitos.

Consegui fazer o programa calcular os dias do ano 1 até o ano 2 como está no meu código:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){

    int dia1, mes1, ano1, dia2, mes2, ano2, diaTotalAno;

    dia1 = 12;
    mes1 = 03;
    ano1 = 2011;

    dia2 = 05;
    mes2 = 10;
    ano2 = 2014;

    // Pega os dias entre ano1 e ano2
    for(int i = ano1; i < ano2; i++){ 

        // verifica se ano é bissexto ou não
        if(i % 4 == 0){
            diaTotalAno += 366;
        } else {
            diaTotalAno += 365;
        }
    }

    for(int i = ano1; i < ano2; i++){ 
        int diaMes +=30;  
    }

    std::cout << "Os dias entre " << ano1 << " e " << ano2 << " é: " << diaTotalAno << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Mas não estou conseguindo calcular os meses nem os dias. Tem como me ajudarem a chegar em uma solução?

Comment: Eu não manjo muito de C++, mas que tal converter as duas datas para timestamps (em segundos), tirar a diferença, e depois dividir por 86400 (`24 * 60 * 60`)?

Comment: Esse algorítimo é um exercício de faculdade, e posso usar apenas if, for e variáveis, por isso q complica muito.

Comment: Isso não é um algoritmo. É um problema :B

Comment: Enfim: se consegues achar a quantidade de dias decorridos, por que não simplesmente transformar os dias em *dia/mês/ano*?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **ATENÇÃO: Você diz claramente que se trata de um trabalho de faculdade. Por isso, existe toda essa necessidade de entender como
>   funcionam os cálculos e implementá-los manualmente. No "mundo real"
>   seria mais fácil já reutilizar algo pronto, que geralmente já existe
>   nas linguagens de programação ou bibliotecas (como em Qt, por exemplo, na classe
>   [QDateTime](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-5.2/qdatetime.html#daysTo)).**
>
> **De todas as formas, eu estou postando esta resposta com o intuito de ajudar também outras pessoas que tenham dúvidas e/ou necessidades
>   similares, *especialmente porque há uma série de conceitos importantes envolvidos*. Por favor, não entenda que eu fiz o código pra você. Se
>   você se sentir tentado a utilizá-lo no seu trabalho sem se preocupar em entender como ele funciona, bom, a escolha é sua. A intenção de trabalhos em faculdade é fazer com que
>   o estudante aprenda, e se você simplesmente copiar você apenas estará
>   desperdiçando *o seu* tempo inutilmente. O recado foi dado.**

A solução mais simples é direta já foi lhe fornecida [em um comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59911/fazer-um-algoritmo-para-calcular-o-n%C3%BAmero-de-dias-decorridos-entre-duas-datas-em#comment123554_59911): se você converter ambas as datas para segundos e então fazer a diferença, você pode dividir esse resultado em segundos por 86400 para ter a diferença em dias. Você poderia converter as datas diretamente para dias, mas a conversão para segundos é melhor porque permite você trabalhar também com horários (ou seja, ter uma estrutura de DataHora ao invés de uma estrutura só de Data).

### Questões Conceituais Importantes

Antes de mais nada, há de se notar algumas questões conceituais *muito importantes*:

1. Para saber se um ano é bissexto **não basta** verificar se ele é divisível por 4. Os anos bissextos existem como forma de ajustar o calendário devido ao fato da terra não girar *exatamente* 365 vezes ao redor de si ao longo do ano, [mas sim aproximadamente 365,242375 vezes](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ano_bissexto#Motiva.C3.A7.C3.A3o_dos_anos_bissextos). Por causa dessa diferença, [foi convencionado o ajuste da seguinte forma](https://www.mathsisfun.com/leap-years.html):

   - A cada 4 anos um dia extra é adicionado (o dia 29 de fevereiro), fazendo com que se tenha 365,25 dias por ano (quando contabilizado em intervalos de 4 em 4 anos). Essa é uma boa aproximação, mas ainda com um erro aproximado de 1 dia a cada 100 anos (0,01 * 100 = 1).
   - Por isso, a cada 100 anos não se adiciona o dia extra, ou seja, o ano (embora divisível por 4) *não é* bissexto (por exemplo, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2100, etc). Assim, tem-se um total de 365,24 dias por ano (quando contabilizado em intervalos de 100 em 100 anos). Esta é uma aproximação muito melhor, mas ainda com erro significativo de quase 1 dia a cada 400 anos (0,002375 * 400 ≈ 1).
   - Assim, a última regra é adicionar 1 dia a cada 400 anos (mesmo o ano sendo divisível por 100), fazendo com que o restante da diferença seja praticamente solucionado e tenha-se um valor bem próximo de 365 dias por ano (quando contabilizado em intervalos de 400 em 400 anos).
2. Se você converter as datas para segundos, precisará usar como referência alguma data inicial (isto é, quando a contagem em segundos de fato começou). É comum usar como referência a data 00:00:00 01/01/0001, pois ela marca o início positivo do [calendário Gregoriano](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calend%C3%A1rio_gregoriano) (zero hora, do primeiro dia, do primeiro mês, do primeiro ano). Por exemplo, com essa referência pode-se dizer que data 00:00:00 12/03/2011 equivale a 63.435.484.800 segundos (decorridos desde 00:00:00 01/01/0001). Deve ser possível perceber que o número de segundos é *bem grande* (mais de 63 bilhões de segundos), e por isso você não pode tratá-lo no seu programa usando valores inteiros simples ([cujo valor máximo é de 4 bilhões, sem sinal em arquitetura de 32 bits](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inteiro_%28ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29)). É por isso que no código de exemplo eu utilizei como tipo de dados o `unsigned long long`, cujo tamanho depende da plataforma mas é garantido pelo Standard C99 a ter [no mínimo 64 bits para representação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5836380/2896619) (permitindo armazenar números inteiros bem grandes, na ordem de [10<sup>18</sup>](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/1000000000000000000) sem sinal).
3. Você também precisa definir para o compilador que os valores inteiros literais digitados (o `86400` do comentário que você recebeu, por exemplo) é um valor longo. Assim você [não incorre em erros de precisão nos cálculos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819398/long-long-int-initialization-warnings). Para fazer isso, basta adicionar `LL` na frente do número literal, fazendo, por exemplo:

> ```
> unsigned long long segundos = 86400LL;
> ```

4. Tome *muito cuidado* ao representar números literais em código escrito em C/C++ com um dígito zero (`0`) à esquerda. Na notação dessas linguagens, isso indica um número literal no [sistema octal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_octal) (base 8) e não no sistema decimal (base 10). Assim, `03` (octal) é igual a `3` (decimal), mas `0016` (octal) não será igual a `16` (decimal), e sim igual a `14` (decimal). Se você intencionou escrever o ano dessa forma, não vai ter o ano que espera. Aliás, se tentar escrever o mês `08` dessa forma, obterá um erro de compilação indicando, por exemplo (no meu compilador, VS 2012):

> ```
> error C2041: illegal digit '8' for base '8'
> ```

Esse erro ocorre porque no sistema octal os dígitos utilizáveis vão somente de 0 a 7 (tal qual no sistema decimal eles vão de 0 a 9). Então, quando for definir as suas datas, use os números literais *sem os zeros iniciais* para não ter problemas. Mais informações [nesta pergunta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568200/what-is-special-about-numbers-starting-with-zero).

### A Implementação

Com base nessas explicações, aqui está um exemplo de código que pode ser construído para realizar os cálculos. Você pode verificar o resultado comparando-o com o de outras fontes, como [esse site](http://www.calculador.com.br/calculo/diferenca-entre-datas) que calcula a diferença entre datas. O site só representa as datas, e o exemplo que eu forneço permite representar também o horário (em horas, minutos e segundos). Então quando for criar datas comparativas, não esqueça de definir a hora, minuto e segundo como 0. O exemplo abaixo testa as datas que você mesmo fornece na pergunta.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Estrutura para representar uma DataHora */
typedef struct _MinhaDataHora {
    int hora;
    int minuto;
    int segundo;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} MinhaDataHora;

/* Função auxiliar para definir os valores da estrutura DataHora */
void defineDataHora(MinhaDataHora *pd, int hora, int minuto, int segundo, int dia, int mes, int ano)
{
    pd->hora = hora;
    pd->minuto = minuto;
    pd->segundo = segundo;
    pd->dia = dia;
    pd->mes = mes;
    pd->ano = ano;
}

/* Função auxiliar para imprimir os valores da estrutura DataHora formatados */
void imprimeDataHora(MinhaDataHora d)
{
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d %02d/%02d/%04d", d.hora, d.minuto, d.segundo, d.dia, d.mes, d.ano);
}

/* Função para verificação se um ano é bissexto */
bool ehBissexto(int ano)
{
    /*
      Um ano só é bissexto se ele for divisível por 4 e NÃO FOR divisível por 100
      (a não ser que ele seja divisível por 100 E TAMBÉM divisível por 400).
    */
    return (ano % 4 == 0) && (ano % 100 != 0 || ano % 400 == 0);
}

/* Função para contar quantos anos bissextos tem entre o ano 1/1/1 e o ano dado */
int contaBissextos(int ano)
{
    return (ano / 4) - (ano / 100) + (ano / 400);
}

/* Função para converter a DataHora dada para segundos */
unsigned long long dataParaSegundos(MinhaDataHora d)
{
    unsigned long long total = 0LL;

    /*
     Primeiro, calcula o tempo decorrido em segundos até a data
     sem contar os anos bissextos, considerando:

     31536000 = número de segundos em um ano não bissexto (365 dias)
     86400 = número de segundos em um dia (24 horas)
     3600 = número de segundos em 1 hora (60 minutos)
     60 = número de segundos em 1 minuto (60 segundos)
    */

    total += (d.ano - 1) * 31536000LL;

    int meses[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    for(int mes = 1; mes < d.mes; mes++)
        total += meses[mes-1] * 86400LL;

    total += (d.dia - 1) * 86400LL;

    total += d.hora * 3600LL;

    total += d.minuto * 60LL;

    total += d.segundo;

    /*
     Então, adiciona segundos para cada dia adicional dos anos bissextos
    */

    /* Número de dias adicionais, para os anos bissextos anteriores ao ano atual */
    int diasExtras = contaBissextos(d.ano - 1);
    total += diasExtras * 86400LL;

    /* Se o mês da data já passou de fereveiro e o ano atual é bissexto, adiciona mais um dia */
    if(ehBissexto(d.ano) && (d.mes - 1) >= 2)
        total += 86400LL;

    return total;
}

/* Função para o cálculo da diferença em segundos entre duas datas */
unsigned long long calculaDiferencaEmSegundos(MinhaDataHora d1, MinhaDataHora d2)
{
    unsigned long long segundosd1 = dataParaSegundos(d1);
    unsigned long long segundosd2 = dataParaSegundos(d2);

    if(segundosd1 > segundosd2)
        return segundosd1 - segundosd2;
    else
        return segundosd2 - segundosd1;
}

/* Função para o cálculo da diferença em dias entre duas datas */
unsigned long long calculaDiferencaEmDias(MinhaDataHora d1, MinhaDataHora d2)
{
    unsigned long long segundos = calculaDiferencaEmSegundos(d1, d2);
    return segundos / 86400LL;
}

/* Função principal do programa */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MinhaDataHora d1, d2;
    defineDataHora(&d1, 0, 0, 0, 12, 3, 2011);
    defineDataHora(&d2, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 2014);

    printf("d1: ");
    imprimeDataHora(d1);
    printf(" (em segundos: %llu)\n", dataParaSegundos(d1));
    printf("d2: ");
    imprimeDataHora(d2);
    printf(" (em segundos: %llu)\n\n", dataParaSegundos(d2));

    printf("Diferenca em segundos entre d1 e d2: %llu\n", calculaDiferencaEmSegundos(d1, d2));
    printf("Diferenca em dias entre d1 e d2: %llu\n", calculaDiferencaEmDias(d1, d2));

    return 0;
}
```

Esse programa resulta na seguinte saída:

```
d1: 00:00:00 12/03/2011 (em segundos: 63435484800)
d2: 00:00:00 05/10/2014 (em segundos: 63548064000)

Diferenca em segundos entre d1 e d2: 112579200
Diferenca em dias entre d1 e d2: 1303
```

A função principal é a `dataParaSegundos`, que realmente faz a conversão sugerida em comentário. Basicamente ela funciona da seguinte forma:

1. Dada uma data, por exemplo, 00:00:00 12/03/2011, ela inicia contabilizando o total de segundos que já passaram até o *ano anterior* (no exemplo, 2010). Simplesmente porque foi só até ai que já se passaram *anos completos* (isto é, 2011 ainda está em andamento e por isso não pode ser considerado completo). Assim, o total em segundos é acumulado com `(d.ano - 1) * 31536000LL`: são 2010 anos vezes o total em segundos de um ano não bissexto (esse número "mágico" é igual ao sugerido em comentário, mas calculado como 60 x 60 x 24 x 365, ou seja, 60 segundos x 60 minutos, para ter os segundos em 1 hora; x 24 horas, para ter os segundos em 1 dia; x 365, para ter os segundos em 1 ano).
2. Os meses são calculados de forma similar (considerando-se apenas até o anterior, pois o atual ainda não está "completo"), mas precisam ser acumulados um a um porque têm quantidades de dias diferentes (por isso o `for` ao invés de multiplicar por um valor único).
3. Os dias são feitos da mesma maneira, considerando-se apenas até o anterior (porque o dia atual também não está completo - ele vai ter algumas horas, minutos e segundos decorridos até 23:59:59, quando mudará para o próximo dia).
4. Só as horas, minutos e segundos que são acumulados normalmente, porque não representam o valor atual incompleto, mas o que já foi completado (2:31:10 indicam exatamente isso: já se passou 2 horas, 31 minutos e 10 segundos).
5. Como esses cálculos intencionalmente ignoram os anos bissextos, basta adicionar tantos dias quantos forem necessários para os bissextos que ocorreram entre 1/1/1 e o ano anterior. No caso do ano atual, só se deve adicionar 1 dia se a data já passou de fevereiro (pois mesmo que ele seja bissexto, se ainda é janeiro não faz sentido adicionar 1 dia).

O restante das funções é auto-explicativa, principalmente com base nas questões conceituais anteriormente discutidas.

Comment: Parabéns, ótima resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, por ser um exercício de faculdade, não postarei aqui o código completo, mas um rascunho para o algoritmo.

Seja d1,m1 e a1 os valores do dia, mês e ano da data mais antiga e d2,m2 e a2 os da data nova.

Primeiro precisamos definir a diferença de dias entre os anos apenas. Podemos usar um for que incremente 1 toda vez que passarmos por um ano divisível por 4 entre os anos dos valores de entrada. O resultado final será `(a2-a1)*(365) + flag_bissexto` que marca quantos dias foram adicionados pelo ano bissexto.

Como temos meses de 28,30 e 31 dias, precisamos calcular a diferença corretamente. Assim identificamos m1 através de IFs como `if(m1%30)` ou `if(m1%31)` ou `if(m1%28)`.

Após isso, precisamos achar quantos dias compõe a diferença entre d1/m1-d2/m2. Caso percebamos que m1=m2, podemos fazer a diferença de dias direto. Caso contrario, precisaremos de outro calculo(sendo aqui um caso de if else comum). Definindo algo como `ja=31,fe=28,mar=31,ab=30,mai=31,jun=30` e assim por diante, podemos fazer um for que incremente uma váriavel em 1 toda vez que passar um dia, e conte até o mês acabar. Quando tivermos contado todos os dias do mês, poderemos somar direto os meses restantes até chegar em m2, quando somamos apenas d2 ao resultado. Perceba que todo mês ímpar tem 31 dias, e todo mês par diferente de 2(fevereiro) tem 30.

Na prática, ficaria em algo do tipo:

d1/m1/a1 = 22/04/1993

d2/m2/a2 = 26/01/2015

(2015-1993)*365 + (5)   será a diferença de dias entre os 2 anos tendo os seguintes anos como bissextos:1996,2000,2004,2008,2012.

Como queremos fazer d1/m1-d2/m2, neste exemplo teremos um resultado negativo, mas será natural e correto, já que de abril para janeiro "avançaremos dias negativos".

Assim teremos -d1(22)-mar(31)-fev(28)-jan(31)+26 = -22-31-28-31(Neste ponto estamos no dia 1/1, assim somamos 26 para chegar à data correta)+26 a diferença dos dias.

Para obter o resultado final basta somar a diferença de dias dos anos com a diferença de dias de d1/m1=d2/m2.

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código na Linguagem C que faz exatamente o que você pediu.
Desenvolvi esse código como uma correção de exercício.
18/09/2020. Espero ajudar a quem precisar. Analisem o código, não apenas copiem. Seu aprendizado depende disso.
Desenvolvido por Jaime Ribeiro Júnior.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int anoi = 0, anof = 0, quantDias = 0, diai=0, diaf=0;
    int mesi=0, mesf =0, anopro = 0, mespro = 0;
    
    printf("Digite o ano inicial -> ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &diai, &mesi, &anoi); getchar();
    printf("Digite o ano final -> ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &diaf, &mesf, &anof); getchar();
    anopro = anoi+1;

    if(anoi != anof){ //ano inical e final diferentes
            //avaliar os anos intermerdiarios 
            // que possuem a quantidade completa de dias
        while(anopro < anof){
            if(anopro%400 == 0) quantDias = quantDias + 366;
            else if(anopro%100 != 0 && anopro%4 == 0) quantDias = quantDias + 366;
            else quantDias = quantDias + 365;
            //printf("dias %d + ", quantDias);// impressão de teste
            anopro++;
        }
        //para ano inicial diferente de ano final.
        //Calculo no ano inicial
        mespro = mesi;
        while(mespro <= 12){
            if(mespro == mesi){//verificação do mês inicial, precisa descontar a quantidade de dias corridos
                if(mesi <= 7 && mesi%2 == 1) quantDias+=31 - (diai - 1);
                //verficande de janeiro a julho
                else if (mesi <= 7 && mesi%2 == 0 && mesi != 2) quantDias+=30 - (diai - 1);
                else if(mesi == 2){
                if(anoi%400 == 0) quantDias = quantDias + 29 - (diai - 1);//C espressão normal
                else if(anoi%100 != 0 && anoi%4 == 0) quantDias += 29 - (diai - 1);//C reduzido
                else quantDias += 28 - (diai - 1);
                } //verificando de agosto a dezembro
                else if(mesi > 7 && mesi%2== 0) quantDias+=31 - (diai - 1);
                else if(mesi > 7 && mesi%2== 1) quantDias+=30 - (diai - 1);
            } else{ //verficação de mês diferente do mês inical
                //verficande de janeiro a julho
                if(mespro <= 7 && mespro%2 == 1) quantDias+=31;// C reduzido 
                else if (mespro <= 7 && mespro%2 == 0 && mespro != 2) quantDias+=30;
                else if(mespro == 2){
                    if(anoi%400 == 0) quantDias = quantDias + 29;// Espressão normal
                    else if(anoi%100 != 0 && anoi%4 == 0) quantDias += 29;//C reduzido
                    else quantDias += 28;
                }//verificando de agosto a dezembro
                else if(mespro > 7 && mespro%2== 0) quantDias+=31;
                else if(mespro > 7 && mespro%2== 1) quantDias+=30;
            }

            mespro++;           
        }
    //printf("dias %d + ", quantDias);// impressão de teste
    //Calculo ano final
        mespro = mesf;
        while (mespro >= 1)
        {
            if(mespro == mesf){//verificação do mês final, só conta a quantidade de dias corridos
                 quantDias+= diaf;
                 
            } else{ //verficação de mês diferente do mês final 
                if(mespro <= 7 && mespro%2 == 1) quantDias+=31;//janeiro a julho
                else if (mespro <= 7 && mespro%2 == 0 && mespro != 2) quantDias+=30;
                else if(mespro == 2){
                    if(anof%400 == 0) quantDias += 29;
                    else if(anof%100 != 0 && anof%4 == 0) quantDias += 29;
                    else quantDias += 28;
                } //agosto a dezembro
                else if(mespro > 7 && mespro%2== 0) quantDias+=31;
                else if(mespro > 7 && mespro%2== 1) quantDias+=30;
            }   
        mespro--;   
        }
    //_________________________________________________________________________________________
    } else {// para ano inicial e ano final iguais
            mespro = mesi;
        while(mespro < mesf){
            if(mespro == mesi){//verificação do mês inicial, precisa descontar a quantidade de dias corridos
                if(mesi <= 7 && mesi%2 == 1) quantDias+=31 - (diai - 1);
                //verficande de janeiro a julho
                else if (mesi <= 7 && mesi%2 == 0 && mesi != 2) quantDias+=30 - (diai - 1);
                else if(mesi == 2){
                if(anoi%400 == 0) quantDias = quantDias + 29 - (diai - 1);//C espressão normal
                else if(anoi%100 != 0 && anoi%4 == 0) quantDias += 29 - (diai - 1);//C reduzido
                else quantDias += 28 - (diai - 1);
                } //verificando de agosto a dezembro
                else if(mesi > 7 && mesi%2== 0) quantDias+=31 - (diai - 1);
                else if(mesi > 7 && mesi%2== 1) quantDias+=30 - (diai - 1);
            } else{ //verficação de mês diferente do mês inical
                //verficande de janeiro a julho
                if(mespro <= 7 && mespro%2 == 1) quantDias+=31;// C reduzido 
                else if (mespro <= 7 && mespro%2 == 0 && mespro != 2) quantDias+=30;
                else if(mespro == 2){
                    if(anoi%400 == 0) quantDias = quantDias + 29;// Espressão normal
                    else if(anoi%100 != 0 && anoi%4 == 0) quantDias += 29;//C reduzido
                    else quantDias += 28;
                }//verificando de agosto a dezembro
                else if(mespro > 7 && mespro%2== 0) quantDias+=31;
                else if(mespro > 7 && mespro%2== 1) quantDias+=30;
            }
            
            mespro++;           
        }
        quantDias+= diaf; // recebendo dias do mes final
    }
    //printf("dias %d", quantDias);// impressão de teste
    
    printf("\nA quantidade de dias foi de %d", quantDias);
}
```