# Código que calcula os dias entre duas datas sem usar o módulo datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo um código que calcula os dias entre duas datas, porém ele não pode usar o módulo datetime, e ele só dá erro.

Eis o código:

```
usuariodata=input()
usuariodata2=input()

Datas=usuariodata.split("/")
Datas1=[int(Datando) for Datando in Datas]

Dia, Mes, Ano = Datas1

MES = Mes-1
NumerosdeDias=0
Contador=1 

while Contador < MES:
    if Contador in (3,5,7,8,10,12):
        NumerosdeDias+=31
    elif Contador in (4,6,9,11):
        NumerosdeDias+=30
    else:
        NumerosdeDias+=28
    Contador+=1

Verifique=(365- NumerosdeDias - Dia - 1)

Datas2=usuariodata2.split("/")
Datas3=[int(Datador) for Datador in Datas2]

Dia1, Mes1, Ano1= Datas3

ANO= Ano1-1
MES1 = Mes1-1
NumeroDeDias=0 
Contadores=1 

while Contadores <= MES1:
  if Contadores in (4,6,9,11):
    NumeroDeDias+=30
  elif Contadores in (1,3,5,7,8,10):
    NumeroDeDias+=31
  else:
    NumeroDeDias+=28
  Contadores+=1
Verificador = (365- NumeroDeDias - Dia1 - 23)

AnoFinal=(Ano1-Ano)
AnoFinal2=AnoFinal*365

if Ano%4 ==0:
  if Mes==2 and Dia==28:
    bissexto=(Ano1-Ano)//4
  else:
    bissexto=(Ano1-Ano)//4-1
elif Ano%4==0:
  if Mes1 ==2:
     bissexto=(Ano1-Ano)//4
  else:
    bissexto=(Ano1-Ano)//4-1
else:
  bissexto=(Ano1-Ano)//4

Verificando = AnoFinal2-bissexto
print(Verifique+Verificador +Verificando)
```

Link de onde ele pode ser executado: https://repl.it/F7rr/2

Comment: Isso pode te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70604/132

Comment: Ah, é importante notar que, para corrigir um erro de 3 dias que se acumulava a cada 400 anos, o Papa Gregório XIII determinou em 1582 uma reforma do calendário que fez com que nem todos os anos divisíveis por 4 sejam bissextos. Desta forma, 1700, 1800 e 1900 não foram bissextos. 2100, 2200 e 2300 também não serão. Mas 1600, 2000 e 2400 são bissextos. O seu programa não leva isso em conta e portanto erra cálculos.

Comment: O colega @VictorStafusa observou muito bem. Se a sua dúvida é o algoritmo que faz o que ele disse, a sua pergunta é mais ou menos duplicada porque [aqui tem a resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60192/73) (ainda que não na mesma linguagem).

Comment: Cara ... se você vai subtrair ou comaparar datas, sem usar o datetime, já está errado para começar.  A não ser que seja so para aprender mesmo,o ut er o gosto de fazer isso, use o datetime. Não tente refazer esse código e por em produção.

A MICROSOFT colocou código errado para datas nos primeiros 5-10 anos do Excel  - datas são coisa smuito fáceis de errar, e muito críticas para qualquer sistema em produção.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa que não te atende na resposta abaixo? Se funcionou, você pode marca-la como aceita?

Answer (score 5):

O seu código tem umas coisas estranhas. A primeiro é acerca do nome duvidoso escolhido para a maioria das variáveis (ex: `Datas`, `Datas1`, `Datas2` e `Datas3`). Vou renomeá-las. E ao renomear, vou levar em conta a [convenção de nomenclatura de variáveis do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Outro problema é em relação a coisas como isso:

```
Verificador = (365- NumeroDeDias - Dia1 - 23)
```

De onde veio esse 23?

Ah, é importante notar que, para corrigir um erro de 3 dias que se acumulava a cada 400 anos, o Papa Gregório XIII determinou em 1582 uma reforma do calendário que fez com que nem todos os anos divisíveis por 4 sejam bissextos. Desta forma, 1700, 1800 e 1900 não foram bissextos. 2100, 2200 e 2300 também não serão. Mas 1600, 2000 e 2400 são bissextos. O seu programa não leva isso em conta e portanto erra cálculos.

Fiz um teste com o seu programa e claramente há algo muito errado nele:

```
 28/02/1900
 01/03/1900
618
```

```
 10/10/2010
 11/10/2010
172
```

Bem, vamos organizar isso tudo. Primeiro eu notei isso:

```
if mes in (3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
```

Cadê o janeiro? O `1` deveria estar lá também!

Observe esse seu `if`:

```
if Ano%4 ==0:
    # ...
elif Ano%4==0:
```

Se `Ano%4==0`, o `if` entra, mas o `elif` não. Em caso contrário nenhum dos dois entra. De todo modo, o `elif` não entra nunca!

Você está calculando os bissextos ao subtrair os números de anos e dividir por 4. Isso não dá certo porque se você considerar um período de 2016 a 2017, o dia bissexto só vai contar se o início for anterior a primeiro de março. Já em um período de 2015 a 2016, o dia bissexto vai contar só se a data final for depois de 29/02. Você apenas verifica o dia 28/02 especificamente, mas isso é insuficiente para pegar o dia bissexto de um período tal como por exemplo, 08/03/2015 a 08/03/2016.

Para arrumar o problema que descrevi no parágrafo anterior, uma forma é na hora de contar os anos bissextos (e apenas nessa hora), você contar por anos que comecem no dia 01/03, como se janeiro e fevereiro fossem os últimos meses ao invés de serem os primeiros. Para isso, basta subtrair 1 do ano se for janeiro ou fevereiro.

Por fim, esse seu `while` com um `if` dentro pode ser separado em uma função para evitarmos ter que duplicá-lo. Também coloquei todo o procedimento de calcular a diferença de datas em uma função.

No caso de a segunda data ser anterior a primeira, para evitar errar cálculos, podemos inverter as datas e então considerar o resultado negativo.

E por fim, para tratar casos onde o usuário digita datas inválidas tais como `32/10/2017`, `29/02/2017`, `00/00/0000`, `99/99/9999` `ab/cd/efgh`, `sorvete-de-abacaxi`, etc, eu uso o [tratamento de exceções do python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html). Para ajudar neste processo, criei as funções `bissexto`, que determina se um ano é bissexto e `validar_data` que determina se uma data é válida ou não.

Assim sendo, eis o código resultante:

```
def dia_no_ano(dia, mes, ano):
  numero_de_dias = dia
  contador_meses = 1
  while contador_meses < mes:
    if contador_meses in (1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12):
      numero_de_dias += 31
    elif contador_meses in (4, 6, 9, 11):
      numero_de_dias += 30
    elif contador_meses == 2:
      numero_de_dias += 28
    contador_meses += 1
  return numero_de_dias

def bissexto(ano):
  return ano % 4 == 0 and (ano % 100 != 0 or ano % 400 == 0)

def validar_data(dia, mes, ano):
  if dia < 1 or dia > 31 or mes < 1 or mes > 12 or ano < 1583:
    return False
  if mes in (4, 6, 9, 11) and dia == 31:
    return False
  if mes == 2 and dia >= 30:
    return False
  if mes == 2 and dia == 29 and not bissexto(ano):
    return False
  return True

def diferenca_data(data1, data2):

  # Separa os dados adequadamente e trata entradas mal-formadas.
  try:
    dia1, mes1, ano1 = [int(datando) for datando in data1.split("/")]
  except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('Data inválida: ' + data1)

  try:
    dia2, mes2, ano2 = [int(datador) for datador in data2.split("/")]
  except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('Data inválida: ' + data2)

  # Verifica se as datas entradas são válidas:
  if not validar_data(dia1, mes1, ano1):
    raise ValueError('Data inválida: ' + data1)
  if not validar_data(dia2, mes2, ano2):
    raise ValueError('Data inválida: ' + data2)

  # Inverte as datas se a data2 anteceder a data1.
  if ano2 < ano1 or (ano2 == ano1 and (mes2 < mes1 or (mes2 == mes1 and dia2 < dia1))):
    return -diferenca_data(data2, data1)

  # Calcula o número de dias nos anos incompletos.
  dias_ano1 = dia_no_ano(dia1, mes1, ano1)
  dias_ano2 = dia_no_ano(dia2, mes2, ano2)

  # Calcula o número de dias totais, considerando os anos incompletos e anos completos de 365 dias.
  dias_total = dias_ano2 - dias_ano1 + (ano2 - ano1) * 365

  # Considera anos começando em 01/03 para poder fazer a correção dos anos bissextos.
  ano1b = ano1
  if mes1 < 3:
    ano1b -= 1

  ano2b = ano2
  if mes2 < 3:
    ano2b -= 1

  # Soma os dias dos anos bissextos. São os divisíveis por 4 que ocorrem entre ano1b e ano2b.
  dias_total += int(ano2b / 4) - int(ano1b / 4)

  # Subtrai os dias dos anos bissextos que não existiram na etapa anterior. São os divisíveis por 100.
  dias_total -= int(ano2b / 100) - int(ano1b / 100)

  # Soma de volta os dias dos anos bissextos que foram removidos a mais na etapa anterior. São os divisíveis por 400.
  dias_total += int(ano2b / 400) - int(ano1b / 400)

  # Resultado da função.
  return dias_total

####### Início do programa. #######

# Lê a entrada do usuário.
x = input()
y = input()

# Calcula a diferença.
diferenca = diferenca_data(x, y)

# Mostra o resultado.
print(diferenca)
```

Eu também fiz os seguintes testes:

```
# Testes
print('Testes:')
print(diferenca_data('28/02/1900', '01/03/1900')) # 1 dia.
print(diferenca_data('28/02/1904', '01/03/1904')) # 2 dias.
print(diferenca_data('28/02/2000', '01/03/2000')) # 2 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2016', '31/12/2016')) # 365 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2016', '01/01/2017')) # 366 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2017', '31/12/2017')) # 364 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2017', '01/01/2018')) # 365 dias.
print(diferenca_data('10/10/2010', '10/10/2410')) # 146097 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2018', '01/01/2017')) # -365 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2017', '01/01/2016')) # -366 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/1899', '01/01/1903')) # 1460 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/1900', '01/01/1904')) # 1460 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/1901', '01/01/1905')) # 1461 dias.
print(diferenca_data('01/01/2000', '01/01/2004')) # 1461 dias.

# Datas válidas.
print('Datas válidas:')
print(validar_data(1, 1, 2001))
print(validar_data(1, 1, 1583))
print(validar_data(31, 12, 99999))
print(validar_data(31, 1, 2016))
print(validar_data(28, 2, 1900))
print(validar_data(28, 2, 2017))
print(validar_data(29, 2, 2000))
print(validar_data(29, 2, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 3, 2016))
print(validar_data(30, 4, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 5, 2016))
print(validar_data(30, 6, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 7, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 8, 2016))
print(validar_data(30, 9, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 10, 2016))
print(validar_data(30, 11, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 12, 2016))

# Datas inválidas:
print('Datas inválidas:')
print(validar_data(0, 1, 2001))
print(validar_data(-1, 1, 2001))
print(validar_data(1, 0, 2001))
print(validar_data(1, -1, 2001))
print(validar_data(1, 13, 2001))
print(validar_data(1, 1, 1582))
print(validar_data(32, 1, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 2, 2016))
print(validar_data(30, 2, 2016))
print(validar_data(29, 2, 1900))
print(validar_data(29, 2, 2017))
print(validar_data(32, 3, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 4, 2016))
print(validar_data(32, 5, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 6, 2016))
print(validar_data(32, 7, 2016))
print(validar_data(32, 8, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 9, 2016))
print(validar_data(32, 10, 2016))
print(validar_data(31, 11, 2016))
print(validar_data(32, 12, 2016))
```

A saída foi exatamente a esperada para todos os testes.

[Veja tudo isso funcionando no *repl.it*.](https://repl.it/F8JU/1)