# Algoritmo para calcular tempo de vida em dias

Tags: c, algoritmo

Queria saber quantos dias eu já vivi, entre a data que nasci até ao dia de hoje, incluindo os anos bissextos. Estou fazendo a seguinte forma, porém não sei como terminar:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
 int dia,diaatual,mes,mesatual,ano,anoatual,totaldias,i;

printf("Digite o dia que você nasceu:\n");
scanf("%d",&dia);
printf("Digite o mes que você nasceu:\n");
scanf("%d",&mes);
printf("Digite o ano que você nasceu:\n");
scanf("%d",&ano);
printf("Digite o dia (data de hoje):\n");
scanf("%d",&diaatual);
printf("Digite o mês (data de hoje):\n");
scanf("%d",&mesatual);
printf("Digite o ano (data de hoje):\n");
scanf("%d",&anoatual);

    for(int i = ano; i < anoatual; i++){ 

        // verifica se ano é bissexto ou não
        if(i % 4 == 0){
            totaldias += 366;
        } else {
            totaldias += 365;
        }
    }

    printf("Dias: %d",totaldias);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Melhore sua pergunta. Esta ocorrendo algum erro? Qual sua dúvida? não Realizou a pergunta...

Comment: Sou iniciante, não estou conseguindo a logica certa pra fazer, quero saber quantos dias eu ja vivi entre a data que nasci e a data de hoje incluindo os anos bissextos ps: em linguagem C ( Se possivel sem usar vetor ou matriz)

Comment: Relacionados: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182280/132 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70604/132

Answer (score 1):

Escrevi essa resposta com base [nesta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70604/132) (lá eu explico isso em maiores detalhes). Apenas traduzi a parte pertinente do algoritmo para C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int restoSemSinal(int a, int b) {
    return (a >= 0L
            ? a % b // Positivo.
            : (b + (a % b)) % b); // Negativo.
}

int divisaoSemSinal(int a, int b) {
    return a >= 0L
            ? a / b // Positivo.
            : (a / b) - (a % b == 0 ? 0 : 1); // Negativo.
}

int contarDiasDesde1970(int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    // Passo 1.
    int anosDesde1970 = ano - 1970;

    // Passo 2.
    int periodosDe400Anos = divisaoSemSinal(anosDesde1970, 400);
    int anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos = restoSemSinal(anosDesde1970, 400);

    // Passo 3.
    int periodosDe4AnosNos400 = anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos / 4;
    int anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos = anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos % 4;

    // Passo 4.
    int diasNosAnosAnterioresDoPeriodoDe4Anos = 365 * anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos + (anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos == 3 ? 1 : 0);

    // Passo 5.
    int diasNoAno = dia - 1;
    int tabelaDeMeses[] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < mes - 1; i++) {
        diasNoAno += tabelaDeMeses[i];
    }

    // Passo 6.
    int dias = diasNoAno
            + diasNosAnosAnterioresDoPeriodoDe4Anos
            + periodosDe4AnosNos400 * 1461
            + periodosDe400Anos * 146097;

    // Passo 7.
    if (anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos == 2 && mes > 2) dias++;
    if (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos > 130 || (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos == 130 && mes > 2)) dias--;
    if (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos > 230 || (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos == 230 && mes > 2)) dias--;
    if (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos > 330 || (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos == 330 && mes > 2)) dias--;

    return dias;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int diaNascimento, diaHoje, mesNascimento, mesHoje, anoNascimento, anoHoje;

    printf("Digite o dia que você nasceu:\n");
    scanf("%d", &diaNascimento);
    printf("Digite o mês que você nasceu:\n");
    scanf("%d", &mesNascimento);
    printf("Digite o ano que você nasceu:\n");
    scanf("%d", &anoNascimento);
    printf("Digite o dia (data de hoje):\n");
    scanf("%d", &diaHoje);
    printf("Digite o mês (data de hoje):\n");
    scanf("%d", &mesHoje);
    printf("Digite o ano (data de hoje):\n");
    scanf("%d", &anoHoje);

    int nascimento = contarDiasDesde1970(diaNascimento, mesNascimento, anoNascimento);
    int hoje = contarDiasDesde1970(diaHoje, mesHoje, anoHoje);
    int diasDeVida = hoje - nascimento;

    printf("Dias: %d", diasDeVida);

    return 0;
}
```

Embora esse algoritmo use como ponto de referência o ano de 1970, ele funciona para qualquer data a partir de 15 de outubro de 1582. Ele poderia utilizar qualquer outro ano completo da era gregoriana (a partir de 1583) como ponto de referência com apenas alguns pequenos ajustes, mas decidi manter 1970 porque é isso que estava no algoritmo original.

Para datas anteriores à reforma do calendário realizada em 1582 (que instituiu o calendário gregoriano), o algoritmo produzirá resultados errados.

Comment: +1 Continua extenso, mas não deixa de ser boa.

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso?
Qualquer dúvida comente...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
 int dia,diaatual,mes,mesatual,ano,anoatual,totaldias;
int anos, meses, dias, diaano, diames;

printf("Digite o dia que você nasceu:\n");
scanf("%d",&dia);
printf("Digite o mes que você nasceu:\n");
scanf("%d",&mes);
printf("Digite o ano que você nasceu:\n");
scanf("%d",&ano);
printf("Digite o dia (data de hoje):\n");
scanf("%d",&diaatual);
printf("Digite o mês (data de hoje):\n");
scanf("%d",&mesatual);
printf("Digite o ano (data de hoje):\n");
scanf("%d",&anoatual); 
//total de anos vividos
anos=anoatual-ano;
// diaano é os anos multiplicados por 365 dias, mais os dias dos anos bissextos, obtido pelo resto a divisao por 4
diaano=(anos%4)+(anos*365);

if(mesatual>mes){
meses=mesatual-mes;
}
else {
meses=mes-mesatual;
}
// meses convertido em dias
diames=meses*30;

if(diaatual>dia){
dias=diaatual-dia;
}
else {
dias=dia-diaatual;
}
totaldias=diames+diaano+dias;
printf("Voce viveu: %d Dias",totaldias);
}
```

Comment: Você sabia que há meses que não têm 30 dias?

Comment: @VictorStafusa  Sabia, mas nao queria dar o código completo... passei uma lógica. E como é algoritmo de iniciante, provavelmente adotem 30 dias como padrão.

Comment: Obrigada, é basicamente isso que eu quero, vou tentar colocar as condições para os meses de dias diferentes

Comment: @AmandaSilva se solucionar, marque como resposta e complemente se quiser... Prazer Ajudar :)